# COS How to set Ens.StringContainer to String Value

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

I like to understand how you can set Ens.StreamConainer to a string value. I just see a class for setting the OriginalFilename but nothing for setting the body.

```
s pRequest = ##class(Ens.StreamContainer).%New()
s pRequest.OriginalFilename = "Test"
d pRequest.Stream.Read(hl7) //Error Out
d pRequest.StreamSet(hl7) //Getting empty string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hl7` is a stream:

```
s pRequest = ##class(Ens.StreamContainer).%New(hl7)
```

It `hl7` is a string:

```
s pStream = ##class(%Stream.GlobalCharacter).%New()
do pStream.Write(hl7)
s pRequest = ##class(Ens.StreamContainer).%New(pStream)
```

---

Some code advice:

> d pRequest.Stream.Read(hl7) //Error Out

`Read` reads from stream, and `Write` writes to stream.

> d pRequest.StreamSet(hl7) //Getting empty string

It is a [setter method](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_propmethods#GOBJ_C12571) for `Stream` property. There's no need to call it directly, just set the property.